# MySQL: ignoring duplicate entries in select

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Test_Results
|ID|Test Name| Status| Retry|
|1 | test1   | passed| 0    |
|2 | test2   | failed| 0    |
|3 | test2   | passed| 1    |
|4 | test3   | failed| 0    |
|5 | test3   | failed| 1    |
|6 | test4   | failed| 0    |
|7 | test4   | failed| 1    |
|8 | test4   | passed| 2    |
```

The logic is the following: if a test failed, then it retried, and the Retry field indicates the number of retries. For example, test 2 failed (ID 2) and succeeded after Retry (ID 3). Or, test4 failed 2 timed (ID's 6 and 7) and succeeded on the 8th time.

I need a query that will select all tests taking only the last retry result. So in case of test2 it will count ID3 = passed, for test3 it will take ID 5 = failed, and for test4 it will take ID 8 = passed.

Comment: My first advice is to throw away `MySQL` and turn to a more reasonable solution, like `Postgresql`, or `MS SQL` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Test_Results t
WHERE t.ID in (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Test_Results GROUP BY Test_Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the max id and not the max retry this way

```
select * from test_results 
where (test_name, id) in select ( test_name, max(id) from test_results group by test_name) )
```

Comment: Fair point, but there was nothing in the question suggesting this, except common sense

Answer (score 0):

Get the max id for a test name and get its results.

```
select * from test_results where id in 
(select max(id) from test_results group by test_name);

+----+-----------+--------+-------+
| id | test_name | status | retry |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+
|  1 | test1     | passed |     0 |
|  3 | test2     | passed |     1 |
|  5 | test3     | failed |     1 |
|  8 | test4     | passed |     2 |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+
```